# Select não retornado dados para os campos

Tags: java, mysql, mvc, crud

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema, estou usando MVC(model view controller),
nas view do projeto deixo a chamada com controller com um metodo que usa o helper pra obter e setar os campos da view e o controller nos seus metodos chama metodos do DAO

o problema acontece na função do select, criei o select para a funcionalidade da pesquisa passando txtPesquisarNome como campo de pesquisa pelo nome

porem ao clcikar no botão, nada acontece, os campos da tela de cadastro login não são preenchidos com os dados vindo no banco, não entra em nenhum else ou catch para me retornar um joptionpane que criei caso tivesse erro

**github:**
https://github.com/YUSEIRENDER/SemurCei

**CadastroLoginController:**

```
public Login selectporNome(String nome) throws SQLException
{        
   
    nome = TelaCadastroLogin.txtPesquisarNome.getText();
    Connection conexao = new Conexao().Conectar();
    LoginDAO loginDAO = new LoginDAO(conexao);   
    Login login = loginDAO.selecioneLoginNome(nome);
    if(login == null)
    {
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login não encontrado!");
        
    }
    else
    {
        
        helper.setModelo(login);
        
        
    }    
    
    return login;
}
```

**CadastroLoginHelper:**

```
    **

    //metodo obter modelo
        public Login obterModelo()
        {
                   
           String usuario = view.getTxtLogin().getText();//string usuario recebe view pegue gettxtlogin e pegue o texto
           String nome = view.getTxtNome().getText();//string nome recebe view pegue getttxtnome e pegue o texto
           String senha =  view.getTxtSenha().getText();//string senha recebe view pegue gettxtsenha e pegue o texto
           String email = view.getTxtEmail().getText();//string email recebe view pegue gettxtemail e pegue o texto
           String tipo = ((String) view.getTxtTipo().getSelectedItem());//string tipo recebe view pegue gettxttipo e pegue o item selecionado
           String data = (view.getTxtData().getText());
           
            //construir objeto do tipo login
            Login login = new Login(usuario,nome,senha,email,tipo, data);      
            return login;
            
            
        }
        
        //metodo para setar o modelo
        public void setModelo(Login login)
        {
            
            view.txtLogin.setText(login.getUsuario());
            view.txtNome.setText(login.getNome());
            view.txtSenha.setText(login.getSenha());
            view.txtEmail.setText(login.getEmail());
            if(view.txtTipo.getItemAt(1).contains("Admin"))
            {
                
                view.txtTipo.setSelectedIndex(1);
                
            }
            else if (view.txtTipo.getItemAt(1).contains("Usuario"))
            {
                
                view.txtTipo.setSelectedIndex(2);
                
            }
                    
            view.txtData.setText(login.getData());
            
        }

**
```

**LoginDAO:**

```
 //metodo para trazer todos logins do banco de dados passando como parametro de pesquisa o nome
 public Login selecioneLoginNome(String nome) throws SQLException {
   Login login = new Login();
    //Faz a instância da classe Login
   String sql = "select * from login where nome = ?";
    //Instrução SQL para seleção de registro específico da tabela login, pelo nome;
    
    nome = view.TelaCadastroLogin.txtPesquisarNome.getText();
    
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstm = conexao.prepareStatement(sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        
        pstm.setString(1, "nome");
        
        ResultSet rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        while(rs.first()){
            //Laço de repetição para preencher com os dados do banco o objeto Login;
            login.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario"));

            login.setSenha(rs.getString("senha"));
            login.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
            login.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));
            login.setData(rs.getString("data"));
            //"seta" os atributos da classe Login com os dados dos campos do banco - pega os dados do banco para pesquisa no formulário
            
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) 
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login não encontrado!" + ex);
        
    }
    finally
    {
            conexao.close(); 
        
    }       
    
  return login;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

tentei depurar os metodos estão sendo chamados, porem o metodo do dão não esta trazendo as informações do banco, esta dando todos os campos como null, porem não entra na clausulas de null e mostra o SQLException na tela

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).